# Best way to ensure that user input confirms with specific format in python?

Tags: python, user-input

I am new to python and I am trying write some code that ensures user input follows the following format:

(Integer):(Integer):(Letter)

So this would be valid:

'3:2:H'

What is the beginners approach to achieving this? Many of the solutions to similar problems that I have read on stackoverflow are a bit too advanced for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Regular expressions are probably what you're after. A bit hard to wrap your head around at first but extremely useful.

Comment: Look at the `re` module.

Comment: The beginner's approach is to learn.

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions are the general answer, but for this specific instance you could write:

```
def validate(in_):
    try:
        a, b, c = in_.split(":")
        _, _ = int(a), int(b)
    except Exception:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Essentially: do a bunch of things that will throw exceptions if the user input is wrong, wrap it in a `try`, and catch any exception with a `return False`. If no exceptions are thrown, well this must be valid so `return True`.

Note that this validates input like:

> 654412:89777056444.12:the entire written works of Shakespeare

but if you're restricting this to one-character only, you could do:

```
def validate(in_):
    try:
        a, b, c = in_.split(":")
        for v in [a, b, c]:
            assert len(v) == 1
        # etc as before
```

---

The general solution, as I mentioned above, is regular expressions.

```
import re

def validate(in_):
    pattern = r"\d:\d:[a-zA-Z]"
    m = re.match(pattern, in_)
    return (m is not None)
```

The pattern here is:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'''
  \d                 # a digit character (0-9)
  :                  # a literal colon
  \d                 # another digit     (0-9)
  :                  # another literal colon
  [a-zA-Z]           # one character from the character class
                     #   containing all letters a-z and A-Z''', re.X)
```

We try to match against this pattern, and simply return whether the match was successful (a failed match leaves `m = None`, while a successful match returns a match object that we don't actually need, so we can safely throw it away. This can be equivalently spelled `return bool(m)`, but that's less explicit about what `m` can be!)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the **argparse** package for getting inputs. Here is the package link [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Below is a sample code I've written using **argparse** and the **regex** module of Python. I used Python3 for running the script.

```
import argparse
import re

class SampleClass:

    def main(self):
        script_description = 'Sample Description for Script'
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=script_description)

        input_one_help = 'Input has format int:int:letter'
        parser.add_argument('input_one',
                            help=input_one_help,
                            type=self._input_one_pattern,
                            metavar='input_one'
                           )

        args = parser.parse_args()
        print(args.input_one)

    @staticmethod
    def _input_one_pattern(input_one):
        try:
            return re.match(r'\d:\d:[a-zA-Z]', input_one).group(0)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('String {}'.format(input_one) + 
                                             'does not match required format.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SampleClass().main()
```